# Can i use facebook API to fetch posts of a public open group/page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can i retrieve facebook-group: posts, comments, images, and other related content from the facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with a public page and I was able to retrieve page /posts, /feed and comments.